# Get dynamically generated tag ids in drop down options using angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to disable "title" (tooltip) generated for each option in angular uib typeahead drop down. Therefore I want to know how to get the dynamically generated tag ids in drop down options using angular JS? Please refer the following html.

```
<input id="main-searchbar" class="form-control" tabindex="2" 
type="text" placeholder="Enter Title, Author, ISBN, or Subject 
keywords" uib-typeahead="item as removeHighLight(item) for item in 
suggest($viewValue)" typeahead-no-results="noResults"     
autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" ng-
model="_value">
```

Comment: That's not a dropdown option afaics it's just a text input box.

Comment: @rrd, uib-typeahead is the library which loads the drop down from its internal implementation.